# Memory size exhausted Autoresponder Sendy

Tags: php, nginx, sendy

I'm using Sendy.co with Nginx and autoresponder it's not working. I checked the cronjob and its running, but when I call 'PHP `/var/www/mywebsite.com/htdocs/autoresponders.php'`

Returns:
`'Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 49152 bytes) in /var/www/mywebsite/htdocs/autoresponders.php on line 141`

I checked the 'PHP.ini' and I have 128MB

Comment: Do we have to guess what your code is or do you help us by posting the code?

Comment: What code? Autoresponders.php? Its part of Sendy.co software. I can post if you want.

Comment: Would be a great start, as not everyone here uses sendy.co software.

Comment: I think there is nothing to do with it, but about increasing memory size elsewhere. The autoresponders.php is huge. But here it is: http://pastebin.com/JY8G1jYN